# VBA Excel odd behaviour

Tags: excel, vba

I've been attempting to write a module that can be imported into any spreadsheet and adapted to manage user account information stored in any sheet within the workbook.

So far I've written the following module:

```
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' modUserSession
'
' The purpose of this module is to provide a layer that manages
' user accounts. 
'
' There is a standard format that must be adheired to, this is
' done by populating the global SessionParams type with the
' relevant information describing the particular sheet where
' the user account information is stored.     
'


Type SessionParameters
    sheetName As String         ' Name of the sheet that contains user accounts
    sheetUnlock As String       ' String to lock/unlock the users sheet

    startRow As Integer         ' Row on which user accounts begin

    nameColumn As Integer       ' Column on which user names are stored
    passColumn As Integer       ' Column on which user passwords are stored
    forenameColumn As Integer   ' Column where user forename is stored
    surnameColumn As Integer    ' Column where user surname is stored
    telephoneColumn As Integer  ' Column where user telephone number is stored
    emailColumn As String       ' Column where user email address is stored
End Type


Type UserAccount
    userName As String
    userPass As String

    foreName As String
    surName As String
    telNum As String
    emailAddr As String
End Type


Private SessionParams As SessionParameters


'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' setSessionParams() 
'
' Populates the global SessionParams that is used to reference the
' relevant sheet where user accounts are stored.
'
Public Function setSessionParams( _
    ByRef sParams As SessionParameters _
)

    SessionParams.sheetName = sParams.sheetName
    SessionParams.sheetUnlock = sParams.sheetUnlock

    SessionParams.startRow = sParams.startRow
    SessionParams.nameColumn = sParams.nameColumn
    SessionParams.passColumn = sParams.passColumn

    SessionParams.forenameColumn = sParams.forenameColumn
    SessionParams.surnameColumn = sParams.surnameColumn
    SessionParams.telephoneColumn = sParams.telephoneColumn
    SessionParams.emailColumn = sParams.emailColumn

End Function


'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' nextEmptyUserRow()    
'
' Will return the next empty row on the sheet referenced by
' the global SessionParams type.
'
Public Function nextEmptyUserRow()

    Dim intRow As Integer

    Dim sheetName As String
    Dim nameColumn As Integer

    sheetName = SessionParams.sheetName
    nameColumn = SessionParams.nameColumn

    intRow = SessionParams.startRow

    While (True)
        If (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Cells(intRow, nameColumn) = "") Then
            nextEmptyUserRow = intRow
            Exit Function
        End If

        intRow = (intRow + 1)
    Wend

End Function


'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' findUserAccount()
'
' Finds the row on which a particular user account is stored and
' returns the row number. 
'
' If the specified user account isn't found then 0 is returned.
'
Public Function findUserAccount( _
    ByVal userName As String _
) As Integer

    Dim intRow As Integer

    Dim sheetName As String
    Dim nameColumn As Integer

    sheetName = SessionParams.sheetName
    nameColumn = SessionParams.nameColumn

    intRow = SessionParams.startRow

    While (True)
        If (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Cells(intRow, nameColumn) = "") Then
            findUserAccount = 0
            Exit Function
        End If

        If (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Cells(intRow, nameColumn) = userName) Then
            findUserAccount = intRow
            Exit Function
        End If

        intRow = (intRow + 1)
    Wend

End Function


'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' loadUserAccountByRow()
'
' Loads a user account from the specified row - even if the row is
' empty and contains no data, the cells are loaded and returned
' in a SessionParameters type and will be empty. 
'
Public Function loadUserAccountByRow( _
    ByVal intRow As Integer _
) As UserAccount

    Dim sheetName As String

    sheetName = SessionParams.sheetName

    loadUserAccountByRow.userName = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Cells(intRow, SessionParams.nameColumn)
    loadUserAccountByRow.userPass = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Cells(intRow, SessionParams.passColumn)
    loadUserAccountByRow.foreName = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Cells(intRow, SessionParams.forenameColumn)
    loadUserAccountByRow.surName = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Cells(intRow, SessionParams.surnameColumn)
    loadUserAccountByRow.telNum = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Cells(intRow, SessionParams.telephoneColumn)
    loadUserAccountByRow.emailAddr = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Cells(intRow, SessionParams.emailColumn)

End Function


'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' loadUserAccountByName()
'
' Loads the specified user account and returns a SessionParameters
' type with the loaded info.
'
' If the specified account doesn't exist then all of the fiels in
' the SessionParameters type will be empty. 
'
' This function works by calling findUserAccount(), passing the
' specified userName as a parameter.
'
' If the account doesn't exist then findUserAccount() will return
' 0, in which case an empty row is loaded.
'
' If the account does exist it is loaded via a call to the
' loadUserAccountByRow() function.
'
Public Function loadUserAccountByName( _
    ByVal userName As String _
) As UserAccount

    Dim intRow As Integer

    ' Get the row on which the user account is stored - the
    ' findUserAccount function will return 0 if the specified
    ' user account does not exist.
    '
    intRow = findUserAccount(userName)

    If (intRow = 0) Then
        ' Return an empty SessionParameters structure.
        '
        loadUserAccountByName = loadUserAccountByRow(nextEmptyUserRow)
    Else
        loadUserAccountByName = loadUserAccountByRow(intRow)
    End If

End Function
```

The idea now is that you populate the global `SessionParameters` variable (`SessionParams` defined in the module) with information relevant to the particular sheet where the data is stored. I basically need to fill the `SessionParams` to indicate the sheet name and the start row/columns where the data is stored.

I have the following sheet:

[image]
So, what I'm doing now is testing the `loadUserAccountByName()` function (from the above module).

So first I have to initialise the global `SessionParams` with the relevant info that points to the sheet and defines where on the sheet everything is.

So when my workbook is first opened I have the following code being executed:

```
Private Function populateSessionParams()

    Dim sParams As SessionParameters
    Dim userRow As Integer


    sParams.sheetName = "Users"
    sParams.sheetUnlock = "UnlockSheet"

    sParams.startRow = 5

    sParams.nameColumn = 4
    sParams.passColumn = 6

    sParams.forenameColumn = 8
    sParams.surnameColumn = 10
    sParams.telephoneColumn = 12
    sParams.emailColumn = 14

    setSessionParams sParams

End Function


Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim uParams As UserAccount

    populateSessionParams

    uParams = loadUserAccountByName("Admin")

    MsgBox _
        "Username: " & uParams.userName & vbCrLf & _
        "Password: " & uParams.userPass & vbCrLf & _
        "Forename: " & uParams.foreName & vbCrLf & _
        "Surname: " & uParams.surName & vbCrLf & _
        "Tel: " & uParams.telNum & vbCrLf & _
        "Email: " & uParams.emailAddr

End Sub
```

In the `Workbook_Open()` function I first call the `populateSessionParams()` function - this initialises the global `SessionParams` defined in the module with appropriate values.

Everything works great except for one thing - the `loadUserAccountByName()` function calls on the `loadUserAccountByRow()` function to populate the `UserAccount` type with the relevant info if it finds a particular user account. And it is finding the Admin account and loading all of the relevant data except for the `emailAddr` member which it refuses to populate.

The error can be traced to the following line from the `loadUserAccountByRow()` function:

```
    loadUserAccountByRow.emailAddr = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Cells(intRow, SessionParams.emailColumn)
```

I can see from the debugger that `SessionParams.emailColumn` definitely contains the value 14 which is the column where email addresses are stored in the Users sheet. I can also see in the debugger that the value of sheetName is indeed "Users"

It populates all other values of the `UserAccount` type using pretty much the same code:

```
' Each of the following lines work.
loadUserAccountByRow.userName = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Cells(intRow, SessionParams.nameColumn)
loadUserAccountByRow.userPass = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Cells(intRow, SessionParams.passColumn)
loadUserAccountByRow.foreName = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Cells(intRow, SessionParams.forenameColumn)
loadUserAccountByRow.surName = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Cells(intRow, SessionParams.surnameColumn)
loadUserAccountByRow.telNum = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Cells(intRow, SessionParams.telephoneColumn)

' This particular line will not work and I get an application or
' object defined error. If I comment this line out, everything works
' great and there are no errors.
'
loadUserAccountByRow.emailAddr = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Cells(intRow, SessionParams.emailColumn)
```

I've been beating my brow over this for a bit now and can't seem to get my head around it. I know it's a bit long winded but you really need all of the code and a reasonable explanation of what I'm trying to do, hope it makes sense.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `SessionParameters.emailColumn` is the only one defined as String: all other column positions are Integer...

Comment: Aaaah! I feel like suc a dope, now. Sweet lord, thankyou.

Comment: Wow, you're lucky you got an answer so quickly, @Tim must be skilled at scanning for key words; that entire 1200 word essay could've been summarized into two sentences.  (See "[mcve]")

Comment: please read and heed [mcve].

Comment: Could an answer be posted please to close this off?

Comment: @Jeeped - *Off-topic Unsolicited Stat of the Day:* Do you realized that, as the #1 VBA and/or Excel answerer, in the last week you've typed 15,700 related words, in **124** posts?  Bad weather for 4x4ing, stuck in on SO eh? ... and QHarr, your wordcount is half of his (with 26 posts) and mine's half of yours (with 18 posts for the week).   ...So much for my lead, haha.

Answer (score 0):

`SessionParameters.emailColumn` is the only one defined as String: all other column positions are Integer.

That is mostly likely the source of the error.